# EntityFramework Core 6.0 Linq Group Join problem ( on "into" word)

Tags: c#, api, linq, left-join, ef-core-6.0

I am using EF Core 6.0 Framework.. And I am coding Web API.. I want to join City and Town Entities like below codes.
But the program is crashing if I use "**into**" word in LinQ query like this "**into tmpTownArr**"  (Its giving GroupJoin Error, I wrote it under the picture)

On Below Picture No 1 and 3 not working, But No 2 and 4 working

[image]

**The Error Code On No 1:**

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<City>()
.GroupJoin(
    inner: DbSet<Town>(), 
    outerKeySelector: c => c.Id, 
    innerKeySelector: t => t.CityId, 
    resultSelector: (c, tmpTownArr) => new { 
        c = c, 
        tmpTownArr = tmpTownArr
     })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Can you please post the code as text instead of screen shot? Insert your <1> <2> as comments.

Comment: I think and I am afraid Yes... :((  (Svyatoslav Danyliv)

Answer (score 0):

Why not redefine how you are using EF and use navigation properties instead of manual joins?

Your problem can be simplified to

```
var townCities = await context.Set<City>.Select(c => new { c, c.Towns }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I will write complex queries on future. So i cant use your solution.  (My problem isnt  get towns with cities. I can get them if I use No 2 above) My problem is i cant use into word in Linq Query.

Comment: My point is, you don't need to explicitly join if your model has correctly defined navigation properties. The point of something like EF is to liberate the programmer from manually writing join statements.

Comment: You have to also consider that linq has to translate your request into a SQL statement; not everything in .net has an equivalent in SQL. Your temporary c# variable doesn't mean much to linq unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you’ve written Linq that can’t be translated to SQL.

One option to fix this is to use AsEnumerable(), but be careful with this as it has a lot of potentially unwanted side effects.

Otherwise you’ll need to come up with an alternate approach.